# Rails 4 with Devise and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Model User has an avatar (as paperclip field generated).
If I want to let user change him avatar on registration's edit page (view is devise/registrations/edit.html.erb), I added this strings to view:

Before I added:

```
multipart: true
```

to HTML-options of the form, after I added:

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

But avatar doesn't change, and there is error in console:

```
Unpermitted parameters: avatar
```

I tryed add custom RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController and add update action with this code:

```
params = params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar)
super
```

But it doesn't work.
And attr_accessible deprecated in Rails 4 and too doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [Devise Strong Parameters documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), you should be adding your `avatar` field to `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user)`.

In your `ApplicationController`:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) << :avatar
  end
end
```

For other approaches in Devise + Strong Parameters please refer to [Devise Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

Comment: Yes, it works, but not ":user"

need ":account_update"

Comment: @ArtemBlanko, Yes you'd have to modify that based on your requirement.

Comment: Hmm, but if I choose the avatar, but not type current password (or any other field, that need for save changes) and press "Save", avatar doesn't show (and 404 routing error in console). After page refresh its ok...

Comment: Are you saying you do not see avatar only when there is a validation error?

Comment: yes, if I get any validation error, I get same page (edit) with invalid avatar image (that I place by "<%= image_tag resource.avatar.url(:full) %>"), in url placed NEW avatar filename (but in DB is old avatar filename).

Comment: @ArtemBlanko did you ever figure out what is causing this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I am not proud of this at all but in my view, I add this line before I display the image: `<% resource.restore_avatar_file_name! %>`. If the view is being displayed due to a validation error, this will reset the filename to the correct value. If the view is being displayed normally without errors, this does nothing. It seems to work but like I said, not proud of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:avatar) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:avatar) }  
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also go to RegistrationController and add :avatar to params there..  (was what I missed)